# htacces ad redirect - is this right?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all my users to another site keeping the current page structure in order to redirect them to the right page on the new domain.

My goal is redirect only the main domain, not the subdomain so I create this snippet but I'm not sure this is right:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com
RewriteRule /(.*) http://otherdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

I already have this in my htaccess that redirect users from www to non-www site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I make sure that if a user comes from `www.domain.com` he will be redirect to the new domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place new rule just below earlier rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However if there is **only one** domain hosted then you can replace those 2 rules by this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```